# Facebook Mobile Notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to send notifications to user through an app, but they don't show in any mobile device.

For example, the user makes an action that sends a notification o other user. If he is on a Computer browser he can see the notification, but in iOS/Android/Mobile Facebook the notification don't show up.

Can you guys help me?

Regrads,
Elkas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about the [Notifications API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-notifications/) where you make a POST request to `/{recipient_userid}/notifications`?

If so, this is intended behaviour. From the docs:

> Note: Only apps on Facebook.com can use the Notifications API. Also
>   these notifications are only surfaced on desktop version of
>   Facebook.com.

Comment: Yes that the one. We noticed that line on the documentation, but still is there any way to get them? We tried apprequests but the app to user apprequest don't show a +1 in the notifications globe. But we want the app to send a notification to there, but we saw the only a apprequest user to user or a Facebook.com app can send it there. Is there any way to send a notification that is showed in the Facebook.com and mobile devices?

Comment: No, this is intentional - user generated requests will show the notification jewel, but app generated requests or notifications will only work for apps on facebook.com